# MDE minimal detectable effect

Tags: mathematical-statistics, experiment-design

I m not able to figure out how to calculate MDE(minimal detectable effect) when designing an experiment. I see that there are calculators to do it for you like this one: https://bit.ly/2XgMjld

For:

- sample size = 10000
- baseline conversion rate = 5%
- confidence level  = 95%
- statistical power = 80%

MDE = 22.52%

I was trying to find a formula which we should use to calculate MDE and get the result as in the example above but I failed.

Can anyone share a formula to calculate MDE or a link to the website where it is described?

Comment: I think you have this backwards. First, in conjunction with subject matter experts, you decide on the MDE then you calculate your necessary sample size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to compute a minimal detectable effect (MDE). Which way you use depends on the kind of statistical test/model you're working with; which is not stated in the body of the question so no one can really provide a formula for MDE without that missing piece of information.

What I can tell you is that MDE is computed by examining two distributions, one produced by the null hypothesis, and another produced by the alternate hypothesis. The computation (whichever one it is) always works the same way:

1 - It establishes the distributions (Normal, t, F,...etc.) based on the type of test/model and the sample size

2 - It computes area under the null hypothesis distribution curve to find a value where the specified confidence level is met.

3 - It uses that value along with the specified power level (which represents the area under the alternate hypothesis distribution curve located beyond the value found in (2)) to shift the alternate hypothesis distribution curve closer to or further away from the null hypothesis distribution curve.

4 - Once the two distributions are in place, the MDE is simply the difference between two points on those two curves (usually the difference in means)

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps better to have an explicit example. Suppose we want to compare two population means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and we collected samples of sizes $n_1,n_2$ for each populations. We have also some prior knowledge of the population standard deviations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$.

Suppose we require confidence level $95\%$ for a one-sided test and power $80\%$, $z$ denotes the distribution of standardised mean difference, we then have

$$
P\left( z + \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2/n_1+\sigma_2^2/n_2}}  > 1.96 \right) = 0.8.
$$

Solving this equation for $(\mu_1-\mu_2)$ and then you get the minimal detectable effect.